# How to include a table while filling text inside a textarea?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textarea

I have a web application in which I am creating posts, for Facebook like feeds. I have a textarea in which I write my post, and then click "Post"

I want to be able to include tables in my post. Like when I am creating a post, i should be able to include a table in it, so that when the post is created and displayed, I can view the table.

```
<%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost..." %>
```

I am just not able to figure out how should I do this.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using a rich text editor. Have a look at [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/).